# changing table height and keeping inside elements centered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The css for `tr` causes the elements inside to not be centered anymore (you can see in the example they're too high up). How should I fix this?

```css
tr {
height: 50px}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that you need the text in table to be centered...

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is because your vertical alignment is being set from bootstrap.

If you were to add this, for example, to your CSS:

```
td, th{
  vertical-align:middle !important;
      }
```

You'll find that your text has been vertically centered within the 50px rows. The issue only becomes apparent when your rows have a large enough space within them to allow text the room to be biased towards one side or the other.

**Note:** the !important declaration is only to fix specificity issues. You can always add classes and/or IDs to allow more specific rules to be set, effectively overriding the default styling coming from bootstrap.

Setting

```
tr {
height: 50px
vertical-align:middle}
```

Won't work, simply because of specificity and the fact that the TD/TH elements require the property in this context.

Here's a demo: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEQgdo

Here's a stackoverflow snippet:

```css
tr {
height: 50px}

td, th{
vertical-align:middle !important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you explain the specificity thing a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
td {
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align:middle !important;
}
```

As you can see:

```css
td {
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align:middle !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @nachime, I think this is a way that works to overcome the  `vertical-align: top;` set by bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `line-height` it should center your text without the need of `!importent`.

```css
tr > td {
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This will create issues with the layout of the table if the data in any cell breaks onto multiple lines.